# How to show FPS in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

My guild member recently uploaded a screenshot of their UI and mentioned world of Warcraft has an in game option to show FPS. I was unable to find this in the settings.

How do you show FPS in WoW?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the "Toggle Framerate Display" command under the Miscellaneous tab of the key bindings menu as seen below.  It is assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> by default.

[image]

Comment: Mine is set to CTRL-R, but pressing that hotkey does not work. Do you need to be in FullScreen mode for it to work?

Comment: @Childishforlife Fullscreen mode shouldn't matter. Do you have any mods that could be blocking it? It appears near the bottom of the screen, just above the action bar.

Comment: Ended up being right in the middle of my screen under my action bars. Can you change the location of the FPS?

Comment: @Childishforlife I'm not aware of a way to do that. There could be a mod though. Might warrant a new question.